# Jquery in React is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

Hi I just want to receive ajax request, but the problem is that jquery is not defined in React. React version is `14.0`

### Error message

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

*I have two files* :

#### `index.js`

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/App';  

const root = document.getElementById('root');  

render( 
  <App source='https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists' />, 
  root
);
```

#### `app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const { source } = this.props;

        console.log($); // throws error
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hey there.</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you defining jQuery anywhere in that code. Why do you think it should work?

Comment: Why even use jQuery with React?

Comment: `const that = this; fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') .then(function(response) { return response.json(); }) .then(function(myJson) { that.setState({data: myJson}); });`

Comment: @mplungjan please make that an answer, with a small explanation on how `fetch` is enough when using ES6 already anyway. Maybe mention that a polyfill can be used for older browsers.

Comment: @EmileBergeron done. Feel free to amend the answer to reflect OPs usage

Comment: @Machycek - please return to the question and finalise it by accepting an answer

Comment: I just have one question. why you use jquery in react? It's much easier to use react libraries or clean javascript

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Try add `jQuery` to your project, like

```
npm i jquery --save
```

or if you use bower

```
bower i jquery --save
```

then

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: If you are using typescript with react, then use `import * as $ from 'jquery';` instead.  more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310361/systemjs-why-am-getting-error-jquery-1-default-is-not-a-function-when-importing

Comment: If you will get an error, try running:


1. yarn install.


2.yarn upgrade.


3.yarn add yarn.


it solved all the problems for me.

Answer (score 7):

It happens mostly when `JQuery` is not installed in your project.
Install JQuery in your project by following commands according to your package manager.

### Yarn

```
yarn add jquery
```

### npm

```
npm i jquery --save
```

After this just import `$` in your project file.
`import $ from 'jquery'`

Answer (score 6):

> *I just want to receive ajax request, but the problem is that jQuery is not defined in React.*

Then don't use it. Use [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and have a look at [Fetch polyfill in React not completely working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125933/fetch-polyfill-in-react-not-completely-working-in-ie-11) to see example of alternative ways to get it running

Something like this

```
const that = this; 
fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') 
  .then(function(response) { return response.json(); }) 
  .then(function(myJson) { 
     that.setState({data: myJson}); // for example
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was really missing from this thread!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't easier than doing like :

1- Install jquery in your project:

```
yarn add jquery
```

2- Import jquery and start playing with DOM:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: I get this error at the runtime: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot define property jQuery360080900754312289092, object is not extensible

Comment: do you have to import $ from 'jquery'; in all js files? I have this import in index.js, when i try to use $ in  a different file i get this error, i thought it will be pass through

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: if you use arrow functions you don't need the const that = this part.
It might look like this:

```
fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') 
  .then((response) => { return response.json(); }) 
  .then((myJson) => { 
     this.setState({data: myJson}); // for example
});
```

Answer (score -12):

Add "ref" to  h1 tag :

```
<h1 ref="source">Hey there.</h1>
```

and
`const { source } = this.props;` change to `const { source } = this.refs;`