# Jspm: Getting error Jquery is undefined after installing and importing foundation

Tags: jquery, systemjs, jspm

This is in an aurelia project but I don't think it is an [aurelia](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.1.1.3) issue

using Typescript 1.7.3 and jspm version 0.16.15

This is just a vanilla setup using skeleton-navigation1.0.0-beta1.1.3/ [typescript-skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.1.1.3). The only change besides importing foundation in the main.ts is the jspm foundation install method as described below.

The error occurs if I do a regular jspm install of foundation as in

> jspm install foundation

If I use a local override everything works as expected.  Install override using

> jspm install foundation=github:zurb/foundation-sites@6.1.2 -o
>   foundation.js

Note: the override file is copied from the registry overrides [foundation override](https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/package-overrides/github/zurb/foundation%406.1.2.json)

In short local override works registry install or registry override does not

override file foundation.js
code

```
{
    "main": "dist/foundation",
    "files": ["dist", "assets", "js", "scss"],
    "shim": {
    "dist/foundation": {
        "deps": "jQuery",
            "exports": "Foundation"
    }
},
    "dependencies": {
    "jQuery": "github:components/jquery"
}
}
```

main.ts  same regardless of foundation install method

code

```
import 'foundation';
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  //Uncomment the line below to enable animation.
  //aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-animator-css');

  //Anyone wanting to use HTMLImports to load views, will need to install the following plugin.
  //aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-html-import-template-loader')

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot())

}
```

Any help is appreciated, been working on this for awhile

Comment: possibly related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310361/systemjs-why-am-getting-error-jquery-1-default-is-not-a-function-when-importing but I have not verified