# TypeError: default is not a function. Import, export JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having a confusion over this supposed to be simple code:

In `driveApi.js`:

```
class GoogleDriveApis {
  constructor(arg) { 
    this.path = arg
  }

  test() {
    console.log(this.path)
  }
}
export default new GoogleDriveApis();
```

When I do:

```
import GoogleDriveApis from './driveApis'

GoogleDriveApis('abc').test()
```

I've got this error: `TypeError: (0 , _driveApis2.default) is not a function`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your imported `GoogleDriveApis` is an *instantiated object*, not a class, did you mean to export: `export default GoogleDriveApis;` (and then use `new` in the consumer)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance +1: I changed to what you said then call `new GoogleDriveApis('abc').test()`

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652423/error-default-is-not-a-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this: `export default new GoogleDriveApis();`

and change your class to be: `export default class GoogleDriveApis {`

Comment: Do you know in which cases we use `export default new GoogleDriveApis()`, then call `GoogleDriveApis('abc').test()` without `new`? I got confusion because I have seen people using it.

Comment: What you linked to seems quite unrelated.

Comment: @lucahuy: It depends on how you want your code to work. Do you want every callsite that uses `./driveApis` to have their own, independent instance of `GoogleDriveApis`? If yes, export the class. But if you want to share the same instance across all modules, export the instantiated object instead. But in that case you probably don't need to define a class first, you can create the object directly.