# Importing modules without a default export in TypeScript (CommonJS)

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to import a module defined without a default export via: `import module from 'module';` and compile it to commonjs?

This [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35950957/1195999) suggests that it is possible with the `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` option passed (albeit only for systemjs modules?).
The [Compiler Options Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) states that `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` only affects typechecking.

Are there any work arounds besides the `import * from module as 'module';` syntax?

Comment: Just curiously, why does the syntax you have to use to import the module matter to you? Why don't you want to use `import * from module as 'module'` if it works?

Comment: A couple reasons:
1) It's ugly
2) It creates a difference between importing a module that intentionally does not have a default export, and a module that does have a default export, albeit in a different syntax. In theory the syntax workaround will need to be altered once (/if) the jquery.d.ts file is updated to properly (imo) export the JQuery function as a default function.

Comment: So ignoring #1 haha, your point #2 isn't really up to you, or up to the `.d.ts` file. If the actual `.js` file defines a default export, then the `.d.ts` file should contain that information and you'll likely import it using `import module from 'module';`  If the actual `.js` file only defines named exports, then the `.d.ts` file will reflect that and you import things using named imports or a wildcard import as mentioned in your post.

TLDR: import syntax you use is determined by the shape of the actual JS module

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is not CommonJS...

CommonJS is the module API implemented by Node, where you use `module.exports`, `exports` and `require` to manage your modules.

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and relies on ES6 native modules. So if you do not want default exports, you should be able to do something like this:

**Your module**

```
export function foo() {
  console.log('Foo');
};

export function bar() {
  console.log('Bar');
};
```

**Your entry point**

```
import {foo, bar} from './module';

foo();
bar();
```

Comment: I want to import JQuery (a non typescript module) into a typescript file without using the `import * as $ from 'jquery';` and compile that file to commonjs.

Comment: Why didn't you put this information in your question? :)