# Fetch is undefined on IE11 when authenticating with cognito

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I have an ember app where I log on and it authenticates me using ember-cognito and ember-simple-auth.

```
this.get('sessionService').authenticate('authenticator:cognito', credentials).then(() => {
         console.log('authenticated');
    }).catch(( reason ) => {

        console.log(reason);
    });
```

This works on every browser except ie which i get the error 'fetch is not defined'.

This appears in the catch section which means cognito is trying to use fetch.

I have been looking into this but cant find a solution for my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include isomorphic-fetch as polyfill to make it work on unsupported browsers.

https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch

Comment: I tried this but its not working with ember and my example :/

Comment: This might help your case particularly for ember https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch

Comment: i have installed this and its still saying fetch is not defined

Comment: it is working now, i had to set window.fetch to ember-fetch. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please install `isomorphic-fetch` polyfill :

> npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise

For more info visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125933/fetch-polyfill-in-react-not-completely-working-in-ie-11)