# How do we import jquery in a React application

Tags: jquery, reactjs, materialize

I want to install jquery and materialize-css into my React application using `npm`, and import it in my React application (I don't want to use CDNs or import in the `index.html` file).

Please how do I do that?

Comment: Just import it with a `<script>` tag before react's `<script>` tag? If you want something else than that, you should also post about your bundling method or how you are currently developing your app?

Comment: npm install jquery ? npm install materialize-css ?

Comment: @cfraser thanks for your reply. I updated the question.

Comment: @leo_ap yeah. but how do I use them in the code?

Comment: have you tried: `var $ = require('jquery')` ? or `import $ from 'jquery'; `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery in React is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351288/jquery-in-react-is-not-defined)

Comment: I just tried this `import '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';` and it seems to be working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a bundler like webpack or browserify. Typically in combination with babel. A quick search gave me this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/setup-a-react-environment-using-webpack-and-babel.

ES6 -> Webpack -> Babel (ES6/JSX) -> ES5 bundle.

Personally I would use this to import more specialized libraries instead of jQuery but you can definitely do this.

Comment: This should work.  After that, you can just import it into your components as needed.