# jQuery plugin gives "jQuery is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins

I am trying to build my own jQuery plugin. Ik looks as follows:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

However, when trying to run this plugin, the error:

```
jQuery is not defined
```

My app.js looks as the following:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
import './greenify';
```

Can anybody help on why this is happening?

## Edit

The issue was that it couldn't find jQuery. Wat fixed the issue was instead of

```
}(jQuery));
```

to type

```
}(global.jQuery));
```

And instead of import './greenify';
do:

```
require('./greenify');
```

Comment: try `}($));` instead of `}(jQuery));`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are importing `$` variable try to changing to

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
        return this;
    };

}($));
```

Comment: Then my error chages to: "$ is not defined". How would this be possible?

Comment: Verify that you have installed jquery in  your packages, and verify if the route is correct...you can do it with this answer...https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351325/2894798

Comment: As per: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ `(function ( $ ) { }(jQuery));` is the correct method to protect the `$` in case it has been used by another plugin.    Adding `$` to the parameters is pointless and might as well not be in the parameters/passed.  Do not do what has been suggested here.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is installed. I have just redone those steps

Comment: @RenzoCalla What should I do then?