# How to import jquery in App.js in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to integrate a bootstrap layout into ReactJS. Here I have face one issue as I missed a jquery file from bootstrap so that my code is not working.
I am very confuse how to integate Jquery in App.js

```
import './App.css';
import './css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/style.css'; 
import './css/slick.css';    
import './js/slick.min.js';   //Jquery
```

Error shows as :

```
Line 17:     'define' is not defined no-undef
Line 17:     'define' is not defined no-undef
Line 17:    'jQuery' is not defined no-undef
Line 17:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an 
             expression  no-unused-expressions
Line 17:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an 
             expression  no-unused-expressions
```

How can i add slick.min.js in App.js

Comment: there is npm is there you can use npm for slick

Comment: Are you linking to a jQuery CDN?

Comment: No i am not using jquery CDN. I am link it from local directory

Answer (score 0):

Referred from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351325/11932228

First try to include jquery into your project

just use npm to install the jquery package:
`npm i jquery --save`

or if you use **yarn**: `yarn add jquery`

or if you use **bower**: `bower i jquery --save`

and in your App.js : `import $ from 'jquery';`

if it still doesn't work you might need to check the requirements of the layout it might not be compatible with react.

Comment: shows that :          $ is declared but its value is never used

Comment: Well did you remove the import of slick.min.js and just import  $, and do it at the top, before import  './App.css'