# React and JQuery plugin ( $ is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

While there have been many answers to this here, it does not seem to be working yet.

- [Jquery in React is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351288/jquery-in-react-is-not-defined/33351325#33351325)
- https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-using-jquery-with-react.html

I'm trying to use the plugin 'jq-timeline' in my project.
I tried to do that:

```
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import timelines from 'jq-timeline/dist/jquery.timeline'
```

But I'm still getting an error

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

**Edit**:
If I remove the plugin import, and print $, I see that it exists.

**Edit2**:

Slove it with:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.$ = $;
const timeline = require('jq-timeline')
```

What do I need to do to view the timeline?

Comment: `import * as $ from 'jquery';` You missed the comment of your first link. Check if this helps.

Comment: I tried it too and it did not work

Comment: Also does not work. If I print the value of $ it is found. Only the plugin does not seem to find it.